# Changing the background color and border color on selection on a tilelist?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I am using a tilelist I want to change the border color and the background color of the tile on selection. Is it possible ????

Thanks in advance

Prashant

Comment: hi friends i got it working by extending Tile List Class and overriding its drawSelectionIndicator method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi friends i got it working by extending Tile List Class and overriding its drawSelectionIndicator method